# Difficult Lagrange multipliers problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let us consider the following convex optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \quad & \mathbf{c}^\top \mathbf{x} \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad & \exp(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}) + \exp(\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d}^\top \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \leq \Gamma, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{d} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are real vectors, $\mathbf{c}$ is not the null vector $\mathbf{0}_n$, $\mathbf{A}$ is a positive definite matrix and $\Gamma$ is a positive constant. The Lagrangian function $\mathcal{L}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, \mu) = \mathbf{c}^\top \mathbf{x} - \mu [\exp(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}) + \exp(\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d}^\top \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \Gamma],
\end{equation*}
where $\mu \geq 0$ is a Lagrange multiplier. Since the Lagrangian is differentiable, the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions hold and are stated as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{c} - \mu[\mathbf{a}\exp(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}) + \mathbf{b}\exp(\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d} + 2\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}] & = \mathbf{0}_{n},\\
\mu [\exp(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}) + \exp(\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d}^\top \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \Gamma] & = 0, \\
\exp(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}) + \exp(\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d}^\top \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \leq \Gamma 
\end{align}
If the last inequality is strict, then the second condition implies that $\mu = 0$. However, this leads to a contradiction in the first equation, since $\mathbf{c} \neq \mathbf{0}_{n}$. Therefore, $\mu > 0$ and we first equations reads
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{a}\exp(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}) + \mathbf{b}\exp(\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}) + 2\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \frac{\mathbf{c}}{\mu} + \mathbf{d}
\end{equation*}
If an explicit solution for $\mathbf{x}$ is found here, it can be plugged in
\begin{equation*}
\exp(\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}) + \exp(\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d}^\top \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \Gamma,
\end{equation*}
thus yielding the value of the Lagrange multiplier. However, since no closed-form solution exists for this problem, I am not sure how to continue solving this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the case $n=1$. Let $\mathbf{c}>0$. Since the left side of the constraint eventually becomes positive for large values of $\mathbf{x}$, the solution is the maximum $\mathbf{x}$ such that $\exp(\mathbf{a} \mathbf{x}) + \exp(\mathbf{b} \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}^2 = \Gamma$. So, the problem is really solving an algebraic equation, as you have discovered using Lagrange multipliers. But I think there is no closed-form solution even $n=1$ case.

Comment: Yes, I agree that no closed-form solution exists in this case. I am asking how to deal with these cases. Is there a way to tackle these problems?

Answer (score 0):

This optimization problem can be numerically solved with a convex conic solver, as cam be conveniently invoked from a convex optimization tool, such as CVX, CVXPY, Convex.jl, CVXR, or YALMIP (which also does non-convex and non-conic modeling).

The CVX (under MATLAB) code is:

```
cvx_begin
variable x(x)
maximize(c'*x)
exp(a'*x) + exp(b'*x) - d'*x + x'*A*x <= Capital_Gamma
cvx_end
```

Mosek is the best solver to specify to be invoked for this problem.

Comment: Yes, I know that this problem can be embedded in any off-the-shelf convex optimization tool such as the ones that you mentioned. However, I have to solve this problem for many different values of the constants and vectors present in the problem. Therefore, I was wondering if it can be solved by other methodologies, in particular using Lagrange multipliers, which can exploit the structure of the problem instead of applying a black-box solver.

Comment: I doubt you will find a better way of solving it using Lagrabge Multipliers.  If you need to solve the problem repeatedly, you can use YALMIP's "optimizer" which allows an optimizer object to be created once, and then used many times with different input data, saving mot of the model creation time for each set of input data.  Unless you pad input data with with zeros, you would need a separate optimizer object for each value of n. But you could change c, a, b, d, A, $\Gamma$ for each problem instance solved. Or you could call Mosek more directly (using Fusion or C API),